# display lines at required position using stroke-dasharray

Tags: javascript, svg, line, stroke-dasharray

I want to display 6 ticks at 0,20,40,60,80,100 from line x1="0" to x2="100" but last line is not display only first 5 are displayed.
I am using the following code

```
<div>
  <svg width="200">
    <line x1="0" x2="100" stroke-width="30" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="1 19 1 19 1 19 1 19 1 19 1"/>
    <line x1="0" x2="100" stroke-width="15" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="0 9 1 19 1 19 1 19 1 19 1 10"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Is there a way to accomplish without changing the line length. And what happens when dash-array has 0 in it? I was not sure

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the end result you are expecting

```html
<div>
  <svg width="200">
    <line x1="0" x2="100" stroke-width="30" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="1 19 1 19 1 19 1 19 1 19 1"/>
    <line x1="0" x2="80" stroke-width="15" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="0 9 1 19 1 19 1 19 1 19 1 10"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I need 1 more major tick at 100 position from first like so total 6 large lines and 5 small lines